# Converting string from GetParameterAsText to uppercase?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I am trying to make a tool in ArcToolbox using a Python script so users can input a street and lot number and it will zoom to the correct location/s in the cadastre. It's working but I have to type the name of the street in upper case in the toolbox and I'd like it work for uppercase or lower.

I assume I should use something like .upper() but I don't know where to put it. I've tried and failed in a few places.

Here's my snippet:

```
RoadName = "'" + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + "'"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
RoadName = "'" + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0).upper() + "'"
```

You can also use the string module:

```
import string
RoadName = "'" + string.upper(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)) + "'"
```